# Why do I have "Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor"?

Tags: realtek, lspci

It seems that everything in my Ubuntu is working properly. I just noticed that when I use

```
lspci
```

The last three lines are,

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07`)

06:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Why does the last line say "Unassigned class [ff00]" ? Is there anything that I need to install or assign?

Comment: All is OK. It is a card reader. There is no a specific class for these devices.

Comment: Please add if you still can use the card reader normally? You can also update the PCI IDs, just in case: `sudo update-pciids && lspci -nn | grep "Card Reader"`

Answer (score 1):

Try something as simple as:

```
modprobe -r rtsx_pci
modprobe rtsx_pci
```

This is because rtsx_pci module manages the card reader. Sometimes it doesn't work properly on boot.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to worry about. This PCI device is a Card reader.

There is no special class for these devices in PCI, so it is shown as  Unassigned class.